# insert a line of code into multiple php files at once

Tags: php, insert, edit

There were some related thread about editing multiple files but none can answer directly or give a solution to my problem.

I have hundreds of files (php files) in a folder, and I need to insert a 1-line of code into all of the files at once.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What have you tried?  How is this more complicated than using the PHP file access functions to open the files and insert lines?

Comment: I just mean that you should post the code you are having problems with.  One of the general criteria for stack overflow questions is that they show some effort to actually solve the problem.  I assume you aren't asking someone to write your program for you  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have A one file that is used in each page . There you can add your one line of Code.

Like You have header file. You can add your code into header file.

If You have more than one header file then you have to add that code in all those header file.
It is better than adding code in multiple 100's of file.

Comment: I have already hundreds of files that I need to edit one by one with the same 1 line of code. It's very tiresome to edit it one by one. I just guess if there's a way to do it with just a click or in a minute.